# Name a variable as string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Assume the variable FileName contains a string such as Name1. How do I make a variable with the name Name1?

The example 4 at this page seems to be similar, but I cant get it to work. Is it the right way to do it?
http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html

Comment: Generally speaking: you probably *don't* want to do this.

Comment: @nkjt: I agree, `eval` is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to do, the `eval` function is there for you:

```
FileName = 'Name1';
eval([FileName ' = 18;']);      % Executes "Name1 = 18;"
```

and now the variable `Name1` is created and has a value of `18`.

The function `genvarname` has a different purpose, which is to generate acceptable and non-conflicting variable names, and not the variables themselves.

Comment: How do you access the variable later in your function? For instance, if you wanted to increment `Name1`? You can't just do `Name1 = Name1 + 1;` because `Name1` isn't know beforehand, right?

Comment: No, it would work since eval actually creates a Name1 variable in the workspace

Comment: How did you know to call the variable `Name1` later in the function but not when you created it?

Answer (score 3):

What you see in "Example 4" is accused as bad programming style. The documentation also contains a section why [to avoid eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

I would recommend a struct with dynamic field names to achieve similar.

```
filename='name1';
mydata=struct();
mydata.(genvarname(filename))=load(filename);
```

Besides better performance, you also get additional functionality when handling multiple files. For example `structfun` to apply a function to all your data or `fieldnames` to get all filenames.

Comment: As a side note ... string `filename` must be a valid property name (no space, no `&`, start with a letter, must not be a keyword and must be less than [`namelengthmax`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/namelengthmax.html) ) ... Name validity can be tested with [`isvarname`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvarname.html)

Comment: Plus 1 for avoiding `eval`.  I would have done the `struct` approach myself.

Comment: Side note also, `mex` function [`mxCreateStructArray`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatestructarray.html?searchHighlight=mxcreatestructarray) does not test its parameters and allows creating structure with invalid field names (see this [mex source](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/88376e034571550a3b82))... Came across the situation no more than 3 days ago and reported this small issue to TMW.

Comment: @CitizenInsane: Added `genvarname` to the solution. Converts to valid variable names, which should also be a valid field name.

Comment: That code produces error message:Error using load
Unable to read file 'name1': no such file or directory.

Comment: @Studenttea: The code is an example supposed to load `name1`, you obviously have to insert your file name.